Error installing skype snap
I am running Ubuntu 22.04. When I try to install skype I get this:Run configure hook of "skype" snap if present (run hook "configure": cannot locate base snap core18: No such file or directory). If I have to reinstall snapd, what happens to all the apps I have from store?
core18                       20231027                    2812   latest/stable    canonical✓     base
core20                       20240111                    2182   latest/stable    canonical✓     base
core22                       20240111                    1122   latest/stable    canonical✓     base
cups                         2.4.7-3                     1024   latest/stable    openprinting✓  -
firefox                      124.0.2-1                   4090   latest/stable    mozilla✓       -```

$ sudo snap remove core18 error: cannot remove "core18": snap "core18" is not removable: snap is being used by snaps gnome-3-28-1804, wine-platform-6-stable and wine-platform-runtime.

Can you run snap refresh core18 ? With or without sudo.

both say no updates available and both ask for password, without sudo it asks for password in gui.

I have removed wine, no error.

This is solved, may be a  help to someone else.
I removed the last application that required core 18 (gnome-3-28-1804), then removed core 18, installed gnome-3-28-1804 which installed core18 also, and after that installing skype worked.
For removal use: sudo snap remove gnome-3-28-1804 --purge
For installation use: sudo snap install gnome-3-28-1804


Remove core18 with
sudo snap remove core18 --purge

and receive:

Error: cannot remove "core18": snap "core18" is not removable: snap is being used by snap vlc.


Then I remove VLC: sudo snap remove vlc --purge

Then I remove successfully core18: sudo snap remove core18 --purge

And successfully install skype: sudo snap install skype


